# Using the == operator twice in a if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, equality-operator

Is it okay to do like this in java, does it work?

```
if (turtles.get(h).getX() == turtles.get(g).getX() == 450) { 
    //stuff here
}
```

Basically, i want to check if X is the same value as Y and that value should be 450.

Comment: Does it compile?  If not, then it probably doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is the same as (turtles.get(h).getX() == turtles.get(g).getX()) == 450 - "incomparable types". `if(turtles.get(h).getX() == 450 && turtles.get(g).getX() == 450)`.

Answer (score 5):

No. What do you expect to happen there?

"a == b" evaluates into a boolean, so "int == (int == int)" would evaluate into "int == boolean", and you cannot compare and int and a boolean.

Besides, what kind of logic are you trying to do here? `if ((a == b) && (b == c))`?

Comment: I want to check if X = Y, and that both X and Y have the value of 450. How do i do that?

Comment: @Jake: Either `(x == y) && (y == 450)` or `(x == 450) && (y == 450)`.

Comment: ...or `(x == z) && (y == z)`, where z is 450 here. (It may be expensive or side-effect-y to compute y).

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not.  This is because the result of `a == b` is a boolean.  If you do `a == b == c` you are first comparing `a == b` which will return `true` or `false` and then comparing that truth value to `c`.

Not what you want to do, usually!

Note that this trick *can* work for assignment because the result of `a = b` is `b` (the new value of `a`) which means `a = b = c` or even `(a = b) == c` come in useful occasionally.

Comment: In Java, assignment is a statement, not an expression, so you can't do "(a = b) == c"

Comment: @Lie: Try/research it before commenting.  It works just fine, and is often used in I/O idioms, e.g. `for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) { //...`

Comment: @Lie: That's because you used it in a statement context.  No expression can be used as a single statement.  Use it like this: `if ((a = b) == c) { //...` and it will work just fine.  Or if you prefer a statement, `boolean myBool = (a = b) == c;`.

Answer (score 2):

Or avoid all the less-readable (and error-prone) repetition with a helper method...

```
public boolean areEqual( int a, int b, int c )
{
    return ( a == b ) && ( b == c ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, because the `==` operator is binary.
And even if it worked sequentially, the first set would return a boolean, which won't work against the integer that follows.

Comment: It's not a problem of `==` being a binary operator. In the OP's example, both instances of `==` work on exactly two operands.  It's a problem of incompatible types (your second point).

Comment: @Mark Peters -- I'm not sure about that.  You think the line `if("1" == "2" == "3")` works now that they're compatible types?  I doubt that.

Comment: Those still aren't compatible types.  it is comparing a boolean to a reference type (String) at the second `==`.  Compatible types would be `myBool1 == myBool2 == true` which works just fine (but is a moronic expression).

Comment: @Mark Peters -- yes, the `true == true == true` will work, but at unexpected result, such as `true == false == false` will evaluate to `true` =)

Comment: from the JLS: "The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right." Both results of your expressions comform to this rule: (((true == true) => true) == true) => true, (((true == false) => false) == false) => true

Answer (score -2):

No it won't work, as explained in the other posts. But you could do

```
if (turtles.get(h).getX() - turtles.get(g).getX() + 450 == 0)
```

Comment: You *could* - but it wouldn't mean the same thing at all.

Comment: Indeed. Trying to be ingenous after 12 hours of work is probably not a good idea ;).

Comment: Maybe you meant `if (a+b == 450*2)`, but you'd get tons of false positives there (a=449, b=451). If you want to check two variables, you need to do two discrete checks.

Comment: Ah, wait, you want to be really sneaky? Let's see. `if ((a^450)|(b^450)) == 0`. How's that? :P